# Determine product from subscription key?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I find myself in a situation where I have a subscription key in a project I inherited, for which I need to determine the product that the key is attached to. We have a couple hundred products, and manually inspecting each one and "show"ing the values of each of its subscription keys is not something I want to do... Is there a way of scripting this? My Googling so far has only revealed solutions for obtaining keys from a known product, which is the opposite of what I need...

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Comment: The best response shows how to do it with PowerShell, but I've never even opened a powershell before, so I have no idea. I battled with it for a while, and had to abandon the task due to time constraints. I've moved on now, so unfortunately, I can't accept the given answer, as I couldn't get it working.

Comment: humm,Interesting

Answer (score 0):

Subscription Key is not unique so you can't get a product using a subscription key as many products from different services might have subscriptions that holds the same subscription keys so no such an api to do this.

In general you can write a script using the list product subscription api and list secrets api to achieve such a thing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/productsubscriptions/list#code-try-0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/subscription/listsecrets#code-try-0

If you are looking just to see to which product a specific call has been made then you can  use any of the solutions below and I prefer the log analytics one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor

Answer (score 0):

If you have a key and want to know which product is the key for, you can use Azure PowerShell: [API management module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/?view=azps-5.4.0) to do this.

Just try the code below:

```
$apimName = "<apim name>"
$apimSresourceGroup = "<apim resource group name>"
$key = "<your ssubscription key>"

$apim_context = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $apimSresourceGroup -ServiceName $apimName

$subs = Get-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $apim_context
foreach($sub in $subs){
    if($sub.PrimaryKey -eq $key -or $sub.SecondaryKey -eq $key){
        write-host 'this key is for product:'$sub.ProductId' belongs to user with ID:' $sub.UserId ' subscription name:'$sub.Name
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Let me know if you have any further questions.